# Redirect to Controller Method Via href Attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, href

I'm developing an ASP.NET core web app and want to redirect the user to a controller method. The following line of code, however, does not work (nothing happens, I think due to no href attribute):

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-dark" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Logout">Sign out</a>
```

This also doesn't work:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Accounts")" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Sign out</a>
```

But this works:

```
<a href="/Accounts/Logout" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Sign out</a>
```

I'm just wondering if redirection directly to a controller method via an href attribute is considered good practice, or if there is a potential alternative that I might try.

This is the generated markup of the three lines of code. The working line of code in the middle. The asp-controller asp-action variant is at the top, and @Url.Action is at the bottom

[image: Working line of code in the middle. asp-controller asp-action variant at the top, and @Url.Action at the bottom]

Comment: Are you sure you are using asp.net-core? Do you have any areas in your project?

Comment: To troubleshoot URL generation related issue, you can try to set the logging level of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` to `TRACE` then check if any useful info in logs.

Answer (score 0):

@Url.Action() -> Contains Typical references; url.Action(string ActionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol, string hostName)

href="/Accounts/Logout" -> has just link name

but if you send an id for example:
`<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { Model.id})"`

you can use like that.